# Creating a new Content Item in the migration with Orchard CMS

Tags: nhibernate, orchardcms-1.6

Here's my migration code:

```
public Migrations(IRepository<ProductPartRecord> productPartRepository, IRepository<CategoryPartRecord> categoryPartRepository)
    {
        _productPartRepository = productPartRepository;
        _categoryPartRepository = categoryPartRepository;
    }

    public int Create() {
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Category", builder => builder
            .WithPart("CommonPart")
            .WithPart("TitlePart")
            .WithPart("AutoroutePart"));

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Category", builder => builder
            .WithPart("AutoroutePart", partBuilder => partBuilder
                .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AllowCustomPattern", "true")
                .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AutomaticAdjustmentOnEdit", "false")
                .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.PatternDefinitions", "[{Name:'Category Title', Pattern: 'category/{Content.Slug}', Description: 'category/category-title'}]")));

        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("CategoryPartRecord", table => table
            .ContentPartRecord()
                .Column<string>("Name")
                .Column<string>("Description")
                .Column<string>("Image")
            );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Category", builder => builder
            .WithPart("CategoryPart"));

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Category", builder => builder
            .Creatable()
            .Draftable());

        return 1;
    }


    public int UpdateFrom1() {

        _categoryPartRepository.Create(new CategoryPartRecord { Name = "Category1", Description = "Description1", Image = "Image1" });

        return 2;
    }
```

UpdateFrom1 obviously attempts to insert a dummy record, but this causes nHibernate to throw this exception:

"attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property: ContentItemRecord"

The Part Record looks like:

```
public class CategoryPartRecord : ContentPartRecord {
    public CategoryPartRecord()
    {
        CategoryProducts = new List<CategoryProductRecord>();
    }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual string Image { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<CategoryProductRecord> CategoryProducts { get; set; }
}
```

Any clues as to where I'm going wrong here? Google produced nothing.

Comment: can you post your updatefrom1 method?

Comment: Hazza, it's at the bottom of the first code block.

Comment: Scrollbars are apparently too hard for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so you are creating a contentpartrecord, not a content item there. What you want is something more along the lines of:

```
var item = _orchardServices.ContentManager.New("Category").As<CategoryPart>();
item.Name = "Bobs Item"; // Something like that...
item.ContentItem.As<TitlePart>().Title = "Yay a title"; // This syntax may be wrong, I'm very tired
_orchardServices.ContentManager.Create(item);
_orchardServices.ContentManager.Publish(item.ContentItem);
```

I think that is how you would do it. Maybe you would want to look into creating content items using the import/export module, that is the more common and safe way to do it.

Comment: Is there something missing from this? When I try this, I get an error at what would be line 2 of the sample code. When trying to access properties of the Part it gives me a null reference error. I'm wondering if the code in line 1 is correct because I would think the string in .New() would be "CategoryPart" not "Category".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the answer from Hazza works. Haven't tried that.
I usually just do this: (But not sure if it's an inferior approach in some way)

```
var item = _orchardServices.ContentManager.New("Category");
var cpart = item.As<CategoryPart>();
var tpart = item.As<TitlePart>();
cpart.Name = "SomeName";
tpart.Title = "SomeTitle";
_orchardServices.ContentManager.Create(item);
```

But to address the comment by Lawrence Johnson:

Category in this case is the content item. He is creating a new Category content item, and then extracting the corresponding CategoryPart from it.

If you are getting null when trying to extract the part you're probably missing something.
In order for this to work you need to implement the CategoryPart, CategoryPartRecord, CategoryPartHandler and CategoryPartDriver. (And of course make sure to attach your CategoryPart to you Category content item. Not certain if placement.info is required, but would add it for consistency anyway.)
You can't leave any of these out if you plan to use a Part attached to a content item.

I'm not sure if/how you can create a Part with no content item, but you can create a Record with no part and no content item (Just make sure you don't inherit ContentPartRecord in your record object). If you simply want to add a record with no part or content item, then the code in UpdateFrom1 used by Ben Power would work for creating a record. (But migration part would have to be changed, taking out the content item and part, and manually setting the Id to be a primary key for the record)